# Redux add item to an existing object in state duplicates entry

Tags: reactjs, redux, lodash

I am using redux and lodash to add an item to the cart. For some reason it duplicates the entry. So I have the same item in the cart object and the cart.items object

My reducer:

```
const INITIAL_STATE = {
    items: {},
    count: null
}

export default (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
    case actionTypes.ADD_CART_ITEM:
        return { ...state, ..._.merge(state.items, { [action.payload.id]: action.payload }) }
    default:
        return state
    }
}
```

My Action

```
export const addCartItem = (item) => {
    return {
        type: actionTypes.ADD_CART_ITEM,
        payload: item
    }
}
```

My Function to add to the cart

```
addToCart() {
        const { selectedSize, selectedShade, selectedQuantity } = this.props.product
        const { id, sku } = this.props.product.product

        if (selectedSize && selectedShade && selectedQuantity) {
            const item = {
                id: id,
                sku: sku,
                size: selectedSize,
                shade: selectedShade,
                quantity: selectedQuantity
            }
            this.props.addCartItem(item)
        } else {
            console.log('you need to select product attributes')
        }
    }
```

My Redux State After adding the item

```
cart: {
    '1': {
      id: 1,
      sku: '7620896024640',
      size: {
        id: 2,
        name: 'Medium',
        prefix: 'M'
      },
      shade: {
        id: 3,
        name: 'Blue',
        prefix: 'Blue',
        color: 'blue'
      },
      quantity: 3
    },
    '9': {
      id: 9,
      sku: '9125620808537',
      size: {
        id: 2,
        name: 'Medium',
        prefix: 'M'
      },
      shade: {
        id: 1,
        name: 'Red',
        prefix: 'Red',
        color: 'red'
      },
      quantity: 1
    },
    items: {
      '1': {
        id: 1,
        sku: '7620896024640',
        size: {
          id: 2,
          name: 'Medium',
          prefix: 'M'
        },
        shade: {
          id: 3,
          name: 'Blue',
          prefix: 'Blue',
          color: 'blue'
        },
        quantity: 3
      },
      '9': {
        id: 9,
        sku: '9125620808537',
        size: {
          id: 2,
          name: 'Medium',
          prefix: 'M'
        },
        shade: {
          id: 1,
          name: 'Red',
          prefix: 'Red',
          color: 'red'
        },
        quantity: 1
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are setting the state incorrectly in your reducer. Can you try replacing it with this:

```
export default (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
    case actionTypes.ADD_CART_ITEM:
        return { ...state, items: {...state.items, [action.payload.id]: action.payload }}
    default:
        return state
    }
}
```

Comment: ```return { ...state, items: {...state.items, { [action.payload.id]: action.payload }}}``` givies a syntax error but ```return { ...state, items: [...state.items, { [action.payload.id]: action.payload }]}``` works but still isnt a solution I want. It creates an array inside items and then adds the item. So it looks like firstitem: cart[items][0][1], seconditem cart[items][1][1]

Comment: Oh sorry. I think the ```[action.payload.id]: action.payload``` should not be wrapped in the braces. I updated the answer. Can you try that, please?

Comment: One little caveat. items is treated as an object and I am failing to iterate through it using .map. Is there an easy way to treat cart.items as an array?

Comment: So what structure you need in the ```items```? Is it an array of objects?

Answer (score 0):

Controls that you don't call 2 times the same action (for example in one another components) or if you are using effects see that you are calling the right actions

Comment: I dont understand?

Comment: If you're saying you might be firing additional actions, I am not. Only one Add to cart acton fires. Im debbugging through redux debugging tools in chrome

Comment: you are using effects??

Comment: No, I am only using classes. useEffects doesnt work in class components

Comment: se that in the reducer you don't call the same action or i really don't know why